# Can I use split method without delete data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My example datatable is below

```
df

col1
100g strawberry
800g apple
904g melon
```

If I try this code below,

```py
df[['col2']] = pd.DataFrame(df.col1.str.split('g', expand=True))
```

I got this result below.

```
df

col1   col2
100     strawberry
800     apple
904     melon
```

I lost my data - 'g' that is necessary.
I want to keep my data that is split keyword.

This table is what I want to get.

```
df

col1   col2
100    g strawberry
800    g apple
904    g melon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove the numbers and write them in a new column(col2) using regex. Then remove the non-numeric expressions for col1.

```
df['col2']=df.col1.str.replace('\d+', '')
df['col1']=df.col1.str.replace('\D+', '').astype('int32')
print(df)
'''
   col1          col2
0   100  g strawberry
1   800       g apple
2   904       g melon
```